Wordpress multisite asset files css, js, images not loading
I have a Multi-site setup in Wordpress. There is a production environment and a staging environment that is a clone of production.
The production environment main site loads, but the sub-sites load with 404 on all the assets:
The staging environment works as expected
When I try to access the same asset file in both environments, it will load on stage:
However not on prod.
My htaccess file  looks like this:
`RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^econo\-cover\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.econo\-cover\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/arscometals\.com\/econo\-cover\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beautifulradiators\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.beautifulradiators\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/arscometals\.com\/beautifulradiators\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit`

What could be causing the discrepancy between stage and prod?
Double checked htaccess file, confirmed wp-config file:
`define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

/* Multisite */
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'arscometals.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );`

